# Martin Isaacs's exercise 3.6 (character theory of finite groups)

Tags: representation-theory, characters

I'm trying to solve this exercise, can anyone help me?

Let $G$ be a p-group, and suppose $\chi\in{Irr(G)}$. Show that $\chi(1)^2$ divides $|G:Z(\chi)|$

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Might I ask what you have tried? Thanks.

Comment: I know that $\chi(1)$ divides $|G|$, but i don't know how to start this. I would need some tip.

Comment: Sorry, what does the notation $Z(\chi)$ mean?

Comment: @GerryMyerson If I remember rightly, $Z(\chi)$ means the set of elements $x\in G$ mapped to diagonal matrices by the representation affording $\chi$.

Comment: Yes. Also $Z(\chi)$ is the set of elements of $G$ that verify $|\chi(g)|=\chi(1)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Use Corollary 2.30 and theorem 3.12.

> By Corollary 2.30, $\chi(1)^2 \leq [G:Z(\chi)]$. By Theorem 3.12, $\chi(1)$ divides $[G:Z(\chi)]$ so is a power of a prime. However $\leq$ is the same as divides for two powers of the same prime. $\square$

Comment: It was simpler than I expected. Thank you very much again, Jack :)